# Does dynamic toggling of "autohideMenuBar" not work?

Tags: javascript, electron

**Electron 7.1.10, Windows 10**

When my app enters full screen, I'm trying to turn off menu visibility and make it "autohide" so it can be accessed through the Alt-key. The code below does turn it off but does not enable the "reveal through Alt-key" behavior.

I've tried commenting out the `mainindow.setMenuBarVisibility();` calls since maybe that is absolute: menu never to be shown, but then the menu still displays in full screen. I've also tried changing the order, so that I call `mainindow.autohideMenuBar = true` before setting visibility to false. No luck.

Has anyone else encountered this?

The [BrowserWindow](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winsetmenubarvisibilityvisible-windows-linux) docs seem to indicate that what I am trying to do should work:

> win.setMenuBarVisibility(visible) Windows Linux
>
> ```
> visible Boolean
> ```
>
> Sets whether the menu bar should be visible. If the menu bar is
>   auto-hide, users can still bring up the menu bar by pressing the
>   single Alt key.

---

```
    if (mainindow.isFullScreen()) {
        // coming out of full screen
        mainindow.setMenuBarVisibility(true);
        mainindow.autohideMenuBar = false
        mainindow.setFullScreen(false);
    } else {
        // entering full screen
        mainindow.setMenuBarVisibility(false);
        mainindow.autohideMenuBar = true
        mainindow.setFullScreen(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So setting the property does not work but using the older method `setAutoHideMenuBar` does – though the [docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winsetautohidemenubarhide) state that that is [deprecated](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/modernization/property-updates#converted-properties). Seems like a bug.

> The Electron team is currently undergoing an initiative to convert
>   separate getter and setter functions in Electron to bespoke properties
>   with get and set functionality. During this transition period, both
>   the new properties and old getters and setters of these functions will
>   work correctly and be documented.

---

> win.setAutoHideMenuBar(hide)
>
> ```
> hide Boolean
> ```
>
> Sets whether the window menu bar should hide itself automatically.
>   Once set the menu bar will only show when users press the single Alt
>   key.
>
> If the menu bar is already visible, calling setAutoHideMenuBar(true)
>   won't hide it immediately.
>
> Deprecated

---

```
if (mainWindow.isFullScreen()) {
    // coming out of FS
    // mainWindow.autohideMenuBar = false
    mainWindow.setAutoHideMenuBar(false);
    mainWindow.setMenuBarVisibility(true);
    mainWindow.setFullScreen(false);
} else {
    // mainWindow.autohideMenuBar = true
    mainWindow.setAutoHideMenuBar(true);
    mainWindow.setMenuBarVisibility(false);
    mainWindow.setFullScreen(true);
}
```